# Authenticate a Cross-Domain Request from Javascript

Tags: javascript, wcf, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to build a public-facing webservice (WCF/Rest) that implements basic authentication.  The problem I'm running into is that in order for the webservice to be accessible, it has to allow for scripting from other domains.  In order to do this, the end user will have to make use of JSONP to get the resonse and JSONP requests do not allow for additional headers (such as the basic authentication header).

I need to be able to support IE8-10, Firefox, and Chrome with this solution.

I've tried changing the url to:

```
http://username:password@Service/Endpoint/Method
```

but to no avail in IE10.

Also I used the suggestion from this post:

http://kevinkuchta.com/_site/2012/01/basic-authentication-with-jsonp/

but it looks like that doesn't cut it in IE10 either.

Comment: Does your current solution work in other browsers besides IE10?

Comment: So, you say you have tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/shahverdy/D2AFR/ ?

Comment: Why don't you implement CORS for those who need to authenficate? You can send the credentials with Ajax.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think IE8 supports CORS and IE8 is the most frequently used browser in our product.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals The image solution will work in Chrome and Firefox, but I'm less than happy about including that as the "appropriate" way for end users to access our webservice.

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy That fails out when trying to read the returned data object because the json can't be accessed from a different domain.

Comment: If you control the service you can simply inject id/password into query string.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example of implementing HTTP auth with JSONP.](http://kevinkuchta.com/_site/2012/01/basic-authentication-with-jsonp/)

It assumes your server will track that the user is authenticated using a cookie. You put the basic auth credentials on a image request, the do the JSONP after you are authenticated.

Alternatively, you can pass querystring parameters with the auth details. Those would work with JSONP. However this clearly is not basic HTTP auth as you requested.